# how to define and use multiple property files using ResourceBundleMessageSource in spring

Tags: java, spring

Can I define two property files using ResourceBundleMessageSource like:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>com/app/view/web/AppResource1</value>
            <value>com/app/view/web/AppResource2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If that is possible with ResourceBundleMessageSource, How to use both the property files in Bean file. Till now, I am using only one property file in any bean by injecting *messageSource* in to it and using like:

```
public class BeanOne {
  public BeanOne(ResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource) {
    this.messageSource = bundleMessageSource;
  }
  ....
  this.messageSource.getMessage("",locale);
}
```

Please tell me how to access both property files in a bean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties from both files are included in the message source.

If you have `com/app/view/web/AppResource1`:

```
com.app.view.web.propertyA=foo
```

And `com/app/view/web/AppResource2`:

```
com.app.view.web.propertyB=bar
```

Then in your bean, you access can them:

```
messageSource.getMessage("com.app.view.web.propertyA", LOCALE); // foo
messageSource.getMessage("com.app.view.web.propertyB", LOCALE); // bar
```